# Why do the following nested loops spin beyond my expectation?

Tags: beamer, loops

Let's consider the following code that reflects my simplified scenario. I want to show a distinct integer for each slides. Of course the real scenario is not to do such a silly thing.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\foreach \x in {0,1,2}{%
    \foreach \y in {0,1}{%
        \only<\numexpr2*\x+\y+1\relax>{\numexpr2*\x+\y+1\relax}}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

My question is why do nested loops spin beyond my expectation? Theoretically there should be 6 slides in total.

Comment: Problems often come from not knowing what I am doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing `\the`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\foreach \x in {0,1,2}{%
    \foreach \y in {0,1}{%
        \only<\the\numexpr2*\x+\y+1\relax>{\the\numexpr2*\x+\y+1\relax}}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

`\numexpr` is like an anonymous count register. For the part inside the `{}` you need `\the` (or `\number` or `\romannumeral` etc) to generate text form just as you would 
had it been `\count@`.  For the one inside `<>` What it does do is fall over the `+` looking for the beamer `<+->` syntax. so you need to expand that away as soon as possible.

Comment: The literal 3 should be changed to 2. I have  made an illogical reasoning in the original question (before I edited).

Comment: @PGFTricks I was going to mention you get more than 6 slides with that formula:-) (done)